# Libgdx / Java Creating / Deleting Bodies creates Java log error

Tags: java, error-handling, libgdx, box2d

everytime I try to delete or create some bodies I get this error log here :

http://pastebin.com/nTgsNdzZ

I delete / Create my bodies so :

Delete :

```
@Override
public void onDead() {

    super.onDead();

    /*
    attackTimer.cancel();
    attackTimer.purge();

    resetTimer.cancel();
    resetTimer.purge();
    */

    if(!game.hostServer && ! gameScreen.launcher.network.client.isConnected()){

        boolean spawned = false;

        while(!spawned){            

            int rdmChance = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(-2, 1 + 1);

            switch (rdmChance) {

            default : 

                spawned = true;

                break;

            case 1:

                HealthTank spawnedTank = new HealthTank(gameScreen, entityBody.getPosition());

                gameScreen.items.add(spawnedTank);

                spawned = true;

                break;

            }

        }

    }

    if(!gameScreen.lightManager.world.isLocked() && entityBody.getUserData() != null && entityBody != null ){

        entityBody.setUserData(null);

        activated = false;

        gameScreen.lightManager.world.destroyBody(entityBody);

    }

    removeNetworkEntity();

}
```

Create :

```
public void randomizeSpawning(){

    int enemyCounter = 0;

    while(enemyCounter < enemyCount){

        int x = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(0, 49 + 1);
        int y = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(0, 49 + 1);

        if(game.grid[y][x] == 1 && SteeringUtils.distanz(new Vector2(x, y), new Vector2(gameScreen.playerEntity.getPosition().x, gameScreen.playerEntity.getPosition().y)) > 500){

               if(!gameScreen.lightManager.world.isLocked()){

                   Body body = gameScreen.createCircleBody(new Vector2(x*Box2dVars.UNIT,y*Box2dVars.UNIT), 20, 0);

                   EnemyEntity entity = new EnemyEntity(gameScreen, body);
                   entity.setUpBehaviors(gameScreen.playerEntity);

                   gameScreen.enemyEntityList.add(entity);

                   PacketMPMob mob = new PacketMPMob();
                   mob.listId = enemyCounter;
                   mob.id = gameScreen.launcher.network.client.getID();
                   mob.position = new Vector2(entity.getPosition().x * Box2dVars.UNIT, entity.getPosition().y * Box2dVars.UNIT);
                   mob.state = entity.getState();
                   mob.isAlive = true;

                   gameScreen.launcher.mobsList.add(enemyCounter, mob);



                   PacketAddMob addMob = new PacketAddMob();
                   addMob.id = gameScreen.launcher.network.client.getID();
                   addMob.listId = enemyCounter;
                   addMob.position = new Vector2(entity.getPosition().x * Box2dVars.UNIT, entity.getPosition().y * Box2dVars.UNIT);

                   System.err.println("POSITIONS : "+new Vector2(entity.getPosition().x * Box2dVars.UNIT, entity.getPosition().y * Box2dVars.UNIT));

                   gameScreen.launcher.network.client.sendTCP(addMob);

                   enemyCounter++;   

            }

        }

    }

}
```

What am I doing wrong?  I check if the world is locked and if than I'll create :/

Comment: Why not use a paste bin for your log? I don't trust random download links.

Comment: It's ok, gonna do that now, but in Not here to spread a virus im here because I need help

Comment: @jpaugh changed it now :)

Comment: Does anyone got some ideas ?

Comment: I really could need some help guys ...

Comment: From the pastebin log, it looks like your program is trying to access memory improperly. This kind of error would be happening in the `C++` internals of `libgdx`. Did you perhaps pass `null` to `libgdx` where it was expecting an object?

Comment: I would search DuckDuckGo for troubleshooting tips regarding `EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION`, particularly those relating to `C++` or `C`. You may have trouble translating those tips into Javaland, but it's a start.

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

--Push--

Still no solution, also i just found out that this only appears, when i destroy a body and right after that spawn a new one

Comment: I'm sorry that your question isn't getting the attention that you'd hoped for. But, this isn't an answer, and should be deleted. An appropriate way to "push" your question would be to improve it further, or add more relevant information.